# Can trial participants get tests?

Tags: clinical-trial

I saw a news story about someone who had participated in a COVID vaccine trial, and he said that he had taken an antibody test that came back positive, and he had concluded that he had not gotten the placebo, but the vaccine, and it had made him immune.

Isn't that problematic behavior? The trial is supposed to be double-blind. Are there ethical guidelines about trial participants getting tested?

Comment: Just because an Ab test came back positive doesn't mean the participant got the vaccine - they may very well have gotten the placebo and later acquired a non-symptomatic infection.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems to be off-topic since it is about ethics rather than biology and "answers" will thus be opinions rather than facts. Thanks! 